# Можно ли использовать JMeter 5.3 с Яндекс.Танк?

Tags: jmeter, яндекс-танк, нагрузочное-тестирование

В описании Docker образа Яндекс.Танка сказано, что используемая версия `JMeter 3.3`.
Будет ли Яндекс.Танк корректно работать с `JMeter 5.3`?

Answer (score 0):

да , в яндекс танк можно запускать тесты из любой версии JMeter. просто нужно в настройках теста в файле load.yaml указать расположение нужного дистрибутива JMeter и ссылку на сценарий написанный в этой версии